# Windows Phone 8 - ASP.Net Master Page Equivalent

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-8, master-pages, mvvm-light

I'm new to Windows Phone 8 Development. I have developed ASP.NET websites before.

My pages (In WP8 Application) share the same headers and footers.

So what is the best method to implement a Master Page like in windows phone 8 ?

I've came across a few solutions that use `Frame` tag ; but they were not applicable.

Any help is highly appreciated.

PS: I'm using MVVM Light Toolkit

I came across this solution but it is a work around:

1- defining `<ControlTemplatex:Key="Decorator" TargetType="ContentControl">` in App.xaml
2- in each page i want that template i just add `<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Decorator}">`

Here is a little detailed sample:

App.xaml

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="Decorator" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid x:Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button x:Name="BackBtn" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </Grid>

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" />

            <Grid x:Name="BottomPanel" Grid.Row="2" Height="50">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Column="0" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" />
                <Button Grid.Column="3" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Now in any xaml page i want to embed that content template i just add the following:

```
    <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource Decorator}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Grid Title" />
            <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Grid.Row="1">
        </Grid>
    </ContentControl>
```

Resource: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82464/How-to-Embed-Arbitrary-Content-in-a-WPF-Control

Comment: Have you done any research into this yourself?  Could you [share your research (what you've tried) with us](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I edited the post. hopefully the edit may help.